# Django - updating user account breaks the user password

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to set up an account update form, where a user can update its info but only when he/she provides its password at the end of the form.

Unfortunately, when I try to update it (even with a correct password), I get logged off and I cannot log back in. I don't know why, but the password breaks completely and I have to reset it via shell.

Also, when I look into the database, the password for each user that I tried to update, it's not hashed anymore, it's just in plain text.

forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username", min_length=4, max_length=50, help_text="Required")
    email = forms.EmailField(
        label="Email",
        max_length=100,
        help_text="Required",
        error_messages={"required": "Sorry, you will need an email"},
    )
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    
    class Meta:
        model = UserAccount
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'about',
            'password'
        ]
    
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields["username"].widget.attrs.update(
            {
                "class": "card bg-dark text-light form-control mb-3",
                "id": 'profile-username'
            }
        )
        self.fields["email"].widget.attrs.update(
            {
                "class": "card bg-dark text-light form-control mb-3",
                "id": 'profile-email'
            }
        )

        self.fields["first_name"].widget.attrs.update(
            {
                "class": "card bg-dark text-light form-control mb-3",
                "id": 'profile-first_name'
            }
        )
        self.fields["last_name"].widget.attrs.update(
            {
                "class": "card bg-dark text-light form-control mb-3",
                "id": 'profile-last_name'
            }
        )
        self.fields["about"].widget.attrs.update(
            {
                "class": "card bg-dark text-light form-control mb-3",
                "id": 'profile-about'
            }
        )
        self.fields["password"].widget.attrs.update(
            {
                "class": "card bg-dark text-light form-control mb-3",
                "placeholder": "Enter password",
                "id": 'profile-password'
            }
        )
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def update_account(request):

    user = request.user

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'You account was successfully updated.')
            return redirect("account:update_account")
        else:
            print(form.errors)

    else:
        form = UserProfileForm(instance=user)
    
    
    return render(request, 'account/account.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: `form.instance.set_password(form.instance.password)` before `form.save()`.

Comment: I'm not trying to set a new password, I just want the user to enter his password as a validation step when he wants to update his account info.